# Google VR - Unity - Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/x86_64/audioplugingvrunity.dll'

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am using `Unity 5.3.5f1 Personal` and I am trying to integrate Unity with `Google VR SDK`. Everything works great with stereoscopic rendering and I can add models to it. But console shows an error:

```
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/x86_64/audioplugingvrunity.dll' with error 'The specified module could not be found.'
```

Everything else works fine.

Background Information: I am using `Windows 10 Pro edition`

As you can see, I have the file audioplugingvrunity.dll in the desired folder but it still gives me a warning message.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like bug. Looks like some got it fixed. Is visual Studio installed on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file exist at the stated path in your project?  Note that in the prior version of the SDK, the filename was very slightly different (old: audiopluginvrunity.dll, new: audioplugingvrunity.dll, i.e. "vr" -> "gvr").  If the old file is still there, delete it in Windows explorer (with Unity closed), reopen Unity, and reimport the SDK.

Comment: Yes, the file exists. All my files are updated to gvr. I will update my post and include a screenshot.

Comment: OK, this bears some further investigation.  The problem I saw in Win10 was that deleting the old file from with Unity did not work, since it was actively in use in the editor.  In your case it seems like the editor is unable to load the dll for some reason.

Comment: Yeah I have read about this issue as well. Didn't try the solution though, mainly because it works fine on the phone. Just another crappy DLL problem. Hope they solve it soon; if it still persists.